# White screen on a LCD screen after downloading driver

Tags: display, touchscreen, driver, lcd

I went through installing the drive and setting it up and it worked but after a few months of not using it, the screen only showed white.

I tried reinstalling it (Downloading the driver, extracting the driver, and running `sudo ./LCD35-show`) a lot of times, I tried rebooting it multiple times but it just won't work.
I used their recommended image (Raspbian) and the screen size was 3.5"
I reinstalled Raspbian and installed the driver but it didn't work
The screen was connected properly so I honestly don't know what went wrong or if it's broken. Please help.

Comment: drive? do you mean driver?

Comment: Yes, I meant driver.